# How to override an inherited CSS style so a link with a class takes that color on hover?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

What should I do when I have 2 a:hover values right above each other, but only the first value is working and the second one not working?

```
<div>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#">Features</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#">Pricing</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="button-go-premium" href="#">Go Premium</a>
</div>
```

```
.button-go-premium {
  border: 3px solid var(--primary-color);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.button-go-premium:hover {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: white;
}
```

I have tried to delete the first value (--primary color), only then the second value (white) is working, but I need to have both values working at the same time. If possible, I do not want to change the order of divs or any of the syntax.

Comment: You want two opposing values working at the same time? or you want to override the  inherited value from navbar when one button has the additional class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As easy and not best practice solution you can use
`color: white !important`

But it's better to add classes for the regular links and for specific links.

```css
.button-go-premium {
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.navbar .link:hover {
  color: red;
}

.link.button-go-premium:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div>
    <a class="link" href="#">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="link" href="#">Features</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="link" href="#">Pricing</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="link" href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="link button-go-premium" href="#">Go Premium</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to change your HTML syntax, you can target the element with more specificity.

Instead of

```
.button-go-premium:hover {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: white;
}
```

Target it with

```
.navbar a.button-go-premium:hover {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: white;
}
```

See the difference? you were previously using this against yourself. You could use more classes like the other answer mentioned, but that can get bulky. You could not touch your HTML and change your CSS to

```
.navbar a:hover {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.button-go-premium {
  border: 3px solid var(--primary-color);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.navbar a.button-go-premium:hover {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: white;
}
```

SCSS Version

```
.navbar {
    // navbar styles
    a {
        // styles for links
        &:hover {
            color: var(--primary-color);
        }
    }
    a.button-go-premium {
        border: 3px solid var(--primary-color);
        border-radius: 15px;
        margin-top: -3px;
        padding-right: 0px;

        &:hover {
            background-color: var(--primary-color);
            color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Anyone reading this should look into the following concepts in CSS*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/specificity

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score -2):

Try to use

```
color: white !important;
```

Comment: I will remove my downvote if you add details on why you made your suggestion. Or would be better if you improve your answer to something more precise.